# Error installing Android 4.2.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean, ota-update, system-freeze

I've received an OTA update to Android 4.2.2 (I'm currently on 4.2.1). However, whenever I try to install it, the process fails partway through. I get an android on its back and the message `Error!` Nothing else. The phone becomes completely unresponsive until I remove the battery. No buttons have any effect.

I don't know what's with those who don't provide any kind of diagnostic info in error messages. How can I install the update?

By the way, my phone, a Galaxy Nexus, is rooted. The system ROM should be stock except that I've integrated most updates into the ROM and converted aLogcat into a system app so it can capture logging data.

Comment: Which Android version is it currently running? Modifications to the `/system` partition (root, integrated updates) might prevent it from updating (if the update checks the CRC of the partition).

Comment: I'm currently on 4.2.1. Other OTA updates have worked OK. I think, though I can't say for sure, that the changes I've made occurred prior to updating to 4.2.1.

Comment: That should be a minor update, agreed, and usually not flash the entire partition. Though it might still check the CRC, not sure about that. Not having a Samsung GNex, I rather leave the answer to somebody who can tell first-hand.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, the gnex is rooted, but stock, other OTA's worked fine. I've tried 3 times now, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just flash the system.img(one from 4.2.1) over your current system, also make sure you're running the corresponding recovery, radio, kernel, and bootloader that came with your takju/yakju factory image.
Do that and and try the OTA again, should work.
"**Flashing system.img didn't wipe data/app**"(Just backup if you are worried about losing data/app) 
**NOTE:You will lose root**

or else try flashing 4.2.2 manually from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1737849)

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Use mobile Odin App. Its simple one.

Comment: Isn't Odin just for regular Samsung devices? Even though Samsung made the Galaxy Nexus, as a Nexus device it's quite different from a typical Samsung device. Also, isn't Odin Windows-only? All my computers are Linux; I don't have Windows or the ability to run Windows software.

Comment: You misunderstood. Mobile Odin is a Mobile App